# android decrease the height of a picture from bottom and from top, in code

Tags: android, height

How do I decrease the height of a picture from bottom and from top, in code? I have two pictures of a tank, a transparent one and a green one that are supposed to be on top of eachother and showing just one part of both pictures so it looks like the tank is half full.
Below is my xml. I am working with fuel_button_green and fuel_button_empty.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/over_fuel_indication"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fuel_button_green"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/tank_green_small"
            android:background="#000000"  />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/fuel_button_empty"
            android:background="#000000" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:src="@drawable/tank_empty_small"/>


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/meter_img_butt"
            android:contentDescription="@string/meter_img_butt"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:background="#000000" 
            android:src="@drawable/meter_small_nodot" /> 

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/meter_dot_img_butt"
            android:contentDescription="@string/meter_img_butt"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:background="#000000" 
            android:src="@drawable/meter_small_dot" /> 

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/bar_img_butt"
            android:layout_width="11dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="121dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/bar_img_butt"
            android:background="#000000" 
            android:src="@drawable/bar_small" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This should be done with animation.

Answer (score 0):

the animation xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="400">
    <scale
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="0.5"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
</set>
```

Comment: Thank you! I used clip to get it work. I had to change the size programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `LayoutParam`

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.fuel_button_green);

button.getLayoutParams().height = XX;
```

or

```
btnsize = button.getLayoutParams();
btnsize.height = XX;
button.setLayoutParams(btnsize);
```

Let me know if it works for you :) - Happy coding!